# How to set separate homeUrl for authenticated users and guests in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I'm wondering is it possible to make different homeUrl for authenticated and guest users? I have such rules in SiteController.php

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                    'denyCallback' => function() {
                        return $this->redirect('/account');
                    }
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'condition'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: I think that there is something wrong in your rule. `signup` is not accessible for the guests, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be much of a problem. My answer is structured as follows:

1. Config for guest users
2. Config for logged in users (overwriting)
3. Alternatives

#### 1. Config for guest users

This one is easy. Simply set the home URL to whatever you want your guest visitors to land on. Put this in your config:

```
//...
'homeUrl'=>'site/home-guests',
//...
```

#### 2. Config for logged in users (overwriting)

A login happens on each and every page-load either via form submission, cookie (remember me), session or access token. You won't notice this since it happens automatically except for the actual form-login.

The `yii\web\User`-class has an event which will be triggered after every login. Its called `yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN`. You can find the doc for the triggering method [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/User.php#L471).

To fulfill your requirement simply extend the user class and within the `init()`-method attach an event handler. If the event mentioned gets thrown, change the home URL. Done!

Heres the code of the custom user class:

```
class User extends \yii\web\User {
    //...
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        //listen to after login event
        $this->on(static::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function ($event) {
            Yii::$app->setHomeUrl(Url::to(['site/home-logged-in']));
        });
    }
    //...
}
```

For Yii to use your custom and extended class, simply tell it to within the config:

```
//...
'user'=>[
    'class'=>'app\components\User',    
],    
//...
```

#### 3. Alternatives

If it's not about the URL but simply to show the users different contents depending on their login-status you have other / easier options:

- show a different view when logged in but use the same action
- redirect them within the action method
- if/else within the actual home-view

Which one is right depends on your detailed requirement. This is difficult to tell with the information you provided.

Tell me if you have further questions. I'll be happy to help!