# Yii2: Change homeUrl depending on the user role

Tags: php, yii2

How can i change the home url depending on the role of the user that is logged in?

I mean, if user has Role Admin make one homeUrl, if it has another role, set a different home url.

I don't just want to redirect the user to the url after loggin, but make the home url different for each user permission.

If user is logged and clicked in nav bar brand, it should go to homeurl of that user.

I think my question is not a duplicate because in my case i don't want to just check if user is guest or not. I want to check the user permission and based on that set the home url.

Comment: see here how to use event after login https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081311/how-to-set-separate-homeurl-for-authenticated-users-and-guests-in-yii2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set separate homeUrl for authenticated users and guests in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081311/how-to-set-separate-homeurl-for-authenticated-users-and-guests-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming REMOTE_USER is getting set you can always based things off of that.  You'll need something (cgi, php, etc.) that can access the variable and direct things based off of it.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `homeUrl` when working in `Yii2`

Comment: yes, I failed to see the Yii2.... would think you could refer to Yii::$app->user->identity in any rule or other url create.